# Vscode does not recognize my remote repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

`VScode` has stopped tracking changes in my repo.

Branch name does not show any more in bottom left hand corner of screen. Try "Pull" command from menu, and I get message "Your repository has no remotes configured to pull from."

On this system git integration with `vscode` had been working perfectly fine for the past 1.5 years; suddenly, it is not working.

Using the command line, I can successfully get the latest changes from the remote repo and also push changes to the remote repo.

Git version is `2.11.0.windows.1`.

Executing the command `git remote -v` from the command line shows that I have a remote repo configured.

Apparently, vscode is not recognizing the remote repo; but why?

## Date

- VS Code version: `Code 1.24.1 (24f6262, 2018-06-13T17:52:25.282Z)`
- OS version: `Windows_NT ia32 6.1.7601`

## Update

I added the following in the User Settings config, and this did not resolve the issue

```
"git.path": "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe"
```

Also, I added this to my Environment Variables (system variables)

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

This did not resolve the issue.

Upgraded to `git version 2.18.0.windows.1`, and this seems to have had no effect on my issue.

Also, TortoiseGit does not recognize my `git.exe` path.  The cause of this issue is probably the same as the cause of my issue with vscode.

I'm not concerned about TortoiseGit but must get vscode git integration working again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a couple things happening but I think the best solution would be to just uninstall and reinstall VS Code.  The issue isn't with Git itself, sounds like an issue with VS Code.  Otherwise you wouldn't be able to execute git commands in general.

When you uninstall VS Code it leaves behind extensions and settings in your local OS user folder, Windows C:\Users\Username.vscode. Meaning when you reinstall, all your stuff will be right there.  And if the problem persists you then know its your settings.

If your settings is the issue, I would just copy all your customized settings to an external file, reset to factory settings and implement one by one.  A little bit of a painful process but will definitely catch your issue.

You could start with your settings from the get go, just copy all of them out and see if it fixes.  Then you know.

Good Luck!